# how post with Django tastypie?

Tags: python, django, post, tastypie

I'm using tastypie in my project, get http method works fine but when i try to post new data i can´t:

```
from random import randint
from django.conf.urls import url
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from device.models import Device
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization, DjangoAuthorization


class DeviceResource(ModelResource):
    service = fields.ToOneField('services.api.resources.ServiceResource', 'service', null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    always_return_data = True
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    fields = ['token', 'description', 'type', 'state','service']
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
    resource_name = 'device'
    autorization = Authorization()
```

Current versions python 2.7.10 django 1.9 tastypie 0.13.3

Comment: The error i have is HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `autorization` -> `authorization`.